# RHEL ssl connect to packages.gitlab.com write:errno=104

Tags: gitlab, openssl, rhel

> cat /etc/redhat-release

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo)

> openssl s_client -servername packages.gitlab.com -connect 
>   packages.gitlab.com:443

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
no peer certificate available
No client certificate CA names sent
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1525425810
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

> curl -I -v packages.gitlab.com

```
* About to connect() to packages.gitlab.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 54.153.54.194...
* Connected to packages.gitlab.com (54.153.54.194) port 80 (#0)
 HEAD / HTTP/1.1
 User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
 Host: packages.gitlab.com
 Accept: */*

* Recv failure: Соединение разорвано другой стороной
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Соединение разорвано другой стороной
[root@demo-git ~]# curl -I -v packages.gitlab.com -k
* About to connect() to packages.gitlab.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 54.153.54.194...
* Connected to packages.gitlab.com (54.153.54.194) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: packages.gitlab.com
> Accept: */*
> 
* Recv failure: Соединение разорвано другой стороной
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Соединение разорвано другой стороной
```

> openssl version

OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017

ca-certificates-2017.2.20-71.el7.noarch 
nss-3.34.0-4.el7.x86_64

On my Ubuntu 18.04

> openssl s_client -servername packages.gitlab.com -connect

```
packages.gitlab.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL, CN = packages.gitlab.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL/CN=packages.gitlab.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
 1 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL/CN=packages.gitlab.com
issuer=/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 5021 bytes and written 330 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: EE1B6E4528F1E9910A334B67D4D2E0DC6C7C367EBE065FA8CEC5B4CFC5FC5A0D
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 4F18D2DC5CFCF503C9F925F091F00CCA96E0742C649A2D24AC0083D10916F82C529AD59E8183C51B5EF7DEC80295850F
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - b1 ee 5f 00 3d 7c 22 85-52 37 1f a4 a7 e4 14 3c   .._.=|".R7.....<
    0010 - 41 1c 00 42 cf 65 d3 c4-ac 80 58 b7 43 14 07 d4   A..B.e....X.C...
    0020 - 6d 98 88 20 99 5b ac 29-54 21 9e 94 d0 4f 80 2f   m.. .[.)T!...O./
    0030 - 98 cf 40 dd 5a a5 c3 3e-92 67 da 51 d2 6d eb 16   ..@.Z..>.g.Q.m..
    0040 - e9 ee ce 31 35 24 60 11-48 13 8e 62 2b b6 27 02   ...15$`.H..b+.'.
    0050 - 86 84 61 63 b5 cd 1a 15-fb a8 11 4a e3 ae cf 3e   ..ac.......J...>
    0060 - 08 6a 97 17 a9 ae 90 b5-6e 06 21 32 94 bc 74 35   .j......n.!2..t5
    0070 - 9c de 27 bc ab 08 b7 64-c3 fb ed b9 a2 29 8f 50   ..'....d.....).P
    0080 - 6b 1a 74 63 20 da 43 56-ce f1 bd c3 03 ec f2 e0   k.tc .CV........
    0090 - 90 95 7d 21 8f 7e 20 57-6d b0 1b b3 03 0f b6 e0   ..}!.~ Wm.......
    00a0 - 0f 63 11 77 61 ff ef 6b-0f c3 df 7f a0 63 ec a1   .c.wa..k.....c..
    00b0 - d7 ef 83 4e d4 8b ff 92-56 5d 90 e3 86 58 7a 52   ...N....V]...XzR

    Start Time: 1525426173
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена, домен заблокирован РКН